# Create a table displaying whether a list is contained within the grouped columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

given the following data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        source=["file1", "file1", "file2", "file2"],
        variable=["shipp", "carrr", "shipp", "bikee"],
    )
)
vals = pd.Series(["ship", "bike"])
```

Which looks as:

```
  source variable
0  file1    shipp
1  file1    carrr
2  file2    shipp
3  file2    bikee
```

I want to create the following:

```
          ship     bike
file1     True     False
file2     True     True
```

I'm not sure how to go about this though, I've tried things along the following:

```
data.groupby("source").apply(
    lambda grp: pd.Series([any(grp["variable"].str.contains(v)) for v in vals])
)
```

This took me a few goes, and I'm now wondering whether there's a nicer approach.

(Any assistance writing a better title is welcome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do `extract` then `pd.crosstab`

```
data['new']=data.variable.str.extract('('+'|'.join(vals)+')')[0]
s=pd.crosstab(data.source,data.new).astype(bool)
new      bike  ship
source             
file1   False  True
file2    True  True
```

Comment: thank you - one thing about this solution is that it seems to be dependent on me mutating the original dataframe ( by adding the `new` column)?

Comment: @baxx pd.crosstab(data.source,data.variable.str.extract('('+'|'.join(vals)+')')[0]).astype(bool)

Comment: out of interest - the `[0]` doesn't seem to be required, is there a reason this was added?

Comment: @baxx that is try get the series, I have behavior when assign the new column always use series